# Incorporate Joomla module into template?

Tags: php, joomla, module

I built a rad slider module. Then I built a template that I am going to use as a base for more projects, and I know I will use my slider module most of the time. Is there a way, other than tearing apart the modules and re-coding it all into the template, to "package" the module with a template?
Like the HTML overrides do, but adding the functionality instead of overriding existing? Does this make sense?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't get the point, can't you simply use
`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="xxxxx" />`
into the template ?

Comment: Well the module operates differently, has to call the helper function, then the layout template and all that.

Comment: @thatryan: sorry, I forgot to use the code tagging and a part of the answer wasn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your put template and the module into a package, which allows installation of multiple extensions at the same time.